Accessing Dependency property with WhenAnyValue
Hello I got a dependency property registered for my UserControl
public partial class MyControl: UserControl

public bool IsReadOnly
 {
     get => (bool)GetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty);
     set => SetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty, value);
 }



public static readonly DependencyProperty IsReadOnlyProperty
    = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsReadOnly), typeof(bool), typeof(MyControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

I'm using ReactiveUI to observe changes to IsReadOnly and enable/disable a command
public MyControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DispatcherScheduler uiScheduler = DispatcherScheduler.Current;

    
    MyCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(ShowSomeAnotherForm,
 this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.IsReadOnly).ObserveOnDispatcher().Select(val => !val), uiScheduler);
   
}

But I get thread error. Inner exception is
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
But I do specify ObserveOnDispatcher().
Tried also combinations of ObserveOn(uiScheduler).SubscribeOn(uiScheduler) but to no avail. Tried direct with RxApp.MainThreadScheduler -> didn't work either.
Tried to specify different combinations of SubscribeOn and ObserveOn. Also tried to channel IsReadOnly to normal property and use that one in command creation.

In your Dependecy Register you specified a wrong type as ownerType. typeof(SearchableInstrumentPicker) is incorrect, you should have wrote typeof(MyControl) instead.

Sorry was leftover from edit.

You will typically get this error when you have forgotten to install the ReactiveUI.WPF package in addition to just the ReactiveUI package:
Install-Package ReactiveUI.WPF

